# Angular input property undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I realize there is a question similarly named already, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong from questions asking the similar things.

I have made a simple checkbox component in angular,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox',
  templateUrl: './check-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./check-box.component.css']
})
export class CheckBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() value: boolean;
  @Input() text: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {    
    console.log("CheckBox component");
    console.log("  " + this.text);
    console.log("  " + this.value);
  }

}
```

The associated template:

```
<div *ngIf="value === false">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <label class="checkbox-label">{{ text }}</label>
</div>
<div *ngIf="value === true">
    <input type="checkbox" checked/>
    <label class="checkbox-label">{{ text }}</label>
</div>
```

The style sheet:

```
div input[type=checkbox]
{
  transform: scale(1.5);  
  padding: 0px;
}

.checkbox-label {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

The component in usage:

`<checkbox [text]="Checkbox" [value]="true" ></checkbox>`

I'm getting an issue where the text property of my CheckBox component is always undefined.  I've tried tinkering with the class, removing the first @Input(), but the issue persists.  Is there something obvious here that is causing the component not to get the property value properly?

Edit:

It was a newbie mistake as pointed out in the comments and answers.

Comment: try `[text]="'Checkbox'"` note the apostrophes.

Comment: Ah... that did it.  Thanks.  I'm sure it was painfully obvious to someone more experienced.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the following expression `[text]="Checkbox"`, you're binding the variable `checkbox` to the `text` input.

I think you want to set the input value as a string, therefore you have to use `[text]="'Checkbox'"` or `text="Checkbox"`.

---

A little side note, your component template isn't optimal, you could just set the `checked` attribute based on the value.

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="value" />
<label class="checkbox-label">{{ text }}</label>
```

---

Apart from that, you should read the documentation for the **[ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)**-directive, because you could have easily used the `ngIfElse` syntax.